# Gatsby.js - Netlify CMS - Netlify Rebuilding

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I am looking into making a project using Gatsby.js and Netlify CMS and I have seen the tutorials and it looks pretty slick, but I am wondering if there is a way to make development less cumbersome.

If I understand correctly, while developing in localhost, if you change something in the Netlify CMS, you have to click "Publish" and then pull down your repo, rebuild and then re-serve the application to have the changes show in your localhost. Is that the only way to do it? Can that be automated?

In production, I guess you don't have a choice but to rebuild the website everytime a change is made in the CMS, but that seems like a step backwards in terms of technology - won't that result in so much downtime of the site? What if people want to edit 10 articles or edit an article again and again - each of those is going to trigger a rebuild and bring the site down, no?

Comment: There's a filesystem option in development: https://github.com/ADARTA/netlify-cms-components/tree/master/packages/netlify-cms-backend-fs

Comment: @DerekNguyen what does that do exactly and how does it work?

Comment: it'll allow you to use local files as backend during development, so you dont have to constantly push and pull to test your data. from the rradme: This is a backend library for NetlifyCMS proposed for file system testing locally during development.

Comment: No, you don't have to rebuild everything on your side, Netlify will do that for you.

Comment: I am the author of the above mentioned file system backend for netlify-cms. It is still beta and the current version of `netlify-cms` broke the use until a correct build of `netlify-cms` with React as an external peer dependency.

Comment: I think this question should be on the netlify/community chat, so I am voting to close it. Your concerns about development are true, that is why I created the library. The concerns about builds in your last paragraph are all invalid, because Netlify works in a totally different way than your assumptions. Your site will NEVER go down because of any build in progress on Netlify. There is always a valid CDN build deployed until the next build is complete and pushed to the CDN.

Comment: https://https://gitter.im/netlify/NetlifyCMS and https://gitter.im/netlify/community

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that (obviously) about the CDN builds. Is that automatic? I will post to the community about development

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of people that will help put your mind at ease about how it works. You may want to close this question yourself, since it does not address a coding issue. Soon Netlify is going to have a place for all of these frequently asked questions.

Comment: Thank you. The building and CDN pushing is automatic though? Netlify handles that? I didnt seem to come across that in the documentation at all

Comment: Automatic site building is the crux of the Netlify service. When there is a commit in your source repository, the site triggers a redeploy using web hooks.

Comment: I am more wondering about the building process without the site going down then the webhook

Comment: I commented on it above. See NEVER

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you understand correctly.

The Netlify CMS is not really designed for use with local development - if you are running the site locally in dev mode, you can just edit the files with a normal text editor.

As the [docs](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/configuration-options/#backend) say, Netlify CMS will always fetch and commit files in your hosted git repository, so you have to pull to see them locally.

The CMS works great for non-developers, who don't want to run a local dev environment, but can still write articles for the site, and then upon publish, wait a few seconds and their article is live on the site.

You are right that multiple edits will trigger multiple re-builds, but Netlify will not disable the old site whilst the new site builds - it will wait for the new build to complete (and pass any tests) before switching up the live version to point at the new build. The site is still usable through the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

There are now some experimental features you could try

`https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/beta-features/#configure-the-netlify-cms-proxy-server-port-number`

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/netlify-cms-proxy-server`